# How to display multiple picker

Tags: swiftui

How to display multiple picker selections?
Selection work with Int state but not array.
My code is the following.

```
@State private var carts = [Cart]()
@State private var selections = [String:Int]()

var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach (self.carts, id: \.id) { cart in
                  Picker(selection: self.$selections[cart.id], label: Text("Select")) {
                        ForEach(1 ..< 100) { num in
                              Text("\(num)")
                        }
                  }
            }
        }
}
```

Is it possible to display multiple picker?

Comment: It is not necessary to put SwiftUI in the title or post body, as you've already added a tag for that language. The tagging system works extremely well here, and does not need any help. Please do not edit it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a`.tag` that matches your selection type.
Since `selections[cart.id]` could be `nil`, your selection type is `Int?`.

Try this:

```
 Text("\(num)").tag(num as Int?)
```

or

```
Text("\(num)").tag(Optional(num))
```

You will need to decide what you want to do if the selection is `nil`.